# apache phoenix DoNotRetryIOException

Tags: apache-phoenix

when i run the sql to create table, like this:

```
    CREATE TABLE FM_DAY(
        APPID VARCHAR NOT NULL,
        CREATETIME VARCHAR NOT NULL,
        PLATFORM VARCHAR NOT NULL,
        USERCOUNT UNSIGNED_LONG,
        LONGCOUNT UNSIGNED_LONG,
        USERCOUNT UNSIGNED_LONG,
        CONSTRAINT PK PRIMARY KEY (APPID,CREATETIME,PLATFORM)
    )
```

this sql has wrong with duplicate key **USERCOUNT**, and error occur when i run it. However, although it thows a exception, this table is created, and the table is exactly like created with this sql:

```
    CREATE TABLE FM_DAY(
        APPID VARCHAR NOT NULL,
        CREATETIME VARCHAR NOT NULL,
        PLATFORM VARCHAR NOT NULL,
        USERCOUNT UNSIGNED_LONG,
        LONGCOUNT UNSIGNED_LONG,
        CONSTRAINT PK PRIMARY KEY (APPID,CREATETIME,PLATFORM)
    )
```

Unfortunately, the follow exception was throwed when excuting both *delete table* and *select table*, and I can't drop this table.

```
    Error: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: FM_DAY: 34
        at org.apache.phoenix.util.ServerUtil.createIOException(ServerUtil.java:84)
        at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.MetaDataEndpointImpl.dropTable(MetaDataEndpointImpl.java:1316)
        at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.generated.MetaDataProtos$MetaDataService.callMethod(MetaDataProtos.java:10525)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.execService(HRegion.java:7435)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.execServiceOnRegion(RSRpcServices.java:1875)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.execService(RSRpcServices.java:1857)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientProtos.java:32209)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2114)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:101)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor.consumerLoop(RpcExecutor.java:130)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$1.run(RpcExecutor.java:107)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 34
        at org.apache.phoenix.schema.PTableImpl.init(PTableImpl.java:354)
        at org.apache.phoenix.schema.PTableImpl.<init>(PTableImpl.java:276)
        at org.apache.phoenix.schema.PTableImpl.makePTable(PTableImpl.java:265)
        at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.MetaDataEndpointImpl.getTable(MetaDataEndpointImpl.java:826)
        at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.MetaDataEndpointImpl.buildTable(MetaDataEndpointImpl.java:462)
        at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.MetaDataEndpointImpl.doDropTable(MetaDataEndpointImpl.java:1336)
        at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.MetaDataEndpointImpl.dropTable(MetaDataEndpointImpl.java:1289)
        ... 10 more
```

If someone know this situation？ And how can I delete this table.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think I ran into this issue before. First, backup your db (in case my instructions don't work `:)`)

Second:

`hbase shell`

Then use hbase commands to disable and then drop the table.

`disable ...`

`drop ...`

After doing this, the table may still show up in Phoenix despite the table not existing in HBase. This is because Phoenix caches metadata in a HBase table. So now you have to find the Phoenix metadata table and drop it (it will be regenerated the next time you start Phoenix).

https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/phoenix-user/201403.mbox/%3CCAAF1JditzYY6370DVwajYj9qCHAFXbkorWyJhXVprrDW2vYYBA@mail.gmail.com%3E